# Displaying user information based on the session variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to display the details of a unit a particular student is taking by using session() but nothing is being displayed in the table.

here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'dbcon.php';

session_start();

$id=$_SESSION['id'];


$sqli="SELECT * FROM unit, student WHERE unit.StudentIDNo = student.StudentID AND StudentIDNo='{$id}'"; 

$record=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);

?>
```

The table should display the details of which unit that particular student is taking based on the session() variable.
So what is my problem here? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: put `session_start()` at the begin of the file, and check it the $id is available

Comment: thanks but its still not working

Comment: have you check the `$_SESSION['id']`??

Comment: can you be specific what you mean by checking the $_SESSION[''id']??

Comment: He means using `print_r($_SESSION);` to see if the id element is set.

Comment: oh thanks..im new to php

Comment: Its giving me this error:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function printr()

Comment: The underscore before the r is important.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove those random quotes from your SQL, like this:

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM unit, student WHERE `unit`.`StudentIDNo` = `student`.`StudentID` AND `unit`.`StudentIDNo` = '$id';";
```

Comment: How are you accessing the $record variable?

Comment: Need more information than this to fix the problem then; error messages, `print_r($_SESSION);` output, etc.

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$sqli="SELECT *
       FROM unit, student
       WHERE 'unit.StudentIDNo' = 'student.StudentID
       AND unit.StudentIDNo' =".$id ;
```

Comment: the result is still blank